# How to hide address bar in inAppBrowser when target is '_system'?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I am using Cordova inAppbrowser plugin to open external URL, and it contains the downloadable PDF file option on button click.

I am using below source code to hide address bar.

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://www.sample-videos.com/download-sample-pdf.php', '_system', 'location=no,hideurlbar=yes,hidenavigationbuttons=yes');
```

*This is happening with the above code:*

When I passed `_system` as the second parameter, the Custom link was opened and PDF file was downloaded when I clicked on the download button whereas in an external link. But address bar of inAppBrowser is still showing.
Here, how to hide address bar?.

When I passed `_blank` as the second parameter, the Custom link was opened and PDF file wasn't downloaded when I clicked on the download button whereas in an external link. But the address bar was hidden. Here, Why PDF file is not downloading?

Now, How to hide the address bar and PDF file also should download?
I am following the below link.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The InAppBrowser options only work when you use `_blank`. When you use `_system` you open Safari and you can't control how it behaves.

That example you are using have a `download` parameter on the link that isn't supported by InAppBrowser, so you should get the direct pdf link and use that url to display the pdf file or make the website redirect to the file instead of using the download attribute.

Might be a bit confusing, but docs say:

> `_blank`: Opens in the `InAppBrowser`.
>
> `_system`: Opens in the system's web browser.
>
> options: Options for the `InAppBrowser`

So, despite the whole plugin is called `InAppBrowser`, you only get the `InAppBrowser` when using `_blank`, and options are only for the `InAppBrowser` window.

P.S, I documented it to try to make it a bit clearer some time ago, so if it's still not clear let me know how we could improve it.

Comment: Thanks for message. I am also assuming the same. but i didn't find any office message which is not supporting the same. Could you share the any links which is emphasis that, is not supporting by InAppBrowser?. or, Is there any option to hide address bar of InAppBrowser when we use target as '_system' ?